# How do I split a vector based on specific value

Tags: pytorch

I have a tensor of the shape `(batch, seq_len)`

```
X = [[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]]
```

I would like to split the above tensor on every row on every col index which has 1. The output should be,

```
X^ = [[0, 0, 0, 1],
      [0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 1],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 1],
      [0, 0, 1],
      [0, 0]]
```

I can loop over rows and do this manually but I believe that operation may not be the most optimal especially when such matrices are on gpus. What would be the optimal way in pytorch to get this transformation.

Comment: So `X` would be a list of tensors, correct?

Comment: Yes X would be a list of tensors.